# Error: Site Settings Navigation

Tags: 2013, error, quick-launch, settings

I am having an issue with the Navigation option on the Site Settings page.

The odd thing is that the Navigation option was operating correctly before. I am trying to make some changes to the quick launch bar (i.e. change URL's etc.). However, when I select "Navigation" an error message appears.

To troubleshoot the issue, I have done the following:

1) checked for any list/libraries that may be returning errors
2) checked to see if there were any pages on the quick launch bar that are producing errors.
3) under Site Administration - Content and Structure works properly
4) searched the correlation id. Nothing returned of significance.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What is error message you are receiving?

Comment: @PhilGreer I am receiving "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred.".  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using managed metadata navigation? Do you receive the same error when browsing to Navigation settings on other sites (`http://yoursite/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`)?

Comment: can you post uls log message?

Comment: @PhilGreer Yes, I am using managed metadata navigation.  No, I do not receive the same error when browsing to Navigation settings on other sites.  Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Did my answer help you?

Comment: @PhilGreer Thank you.  Yes, your answer was very helpful.  The issue is still present, but I think it's other things that are causing the error.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Ensure Managed Metadata Service / Connections are functioning without problems
- If recent changes were made to terms, these changes may impact your navigation. Consider rolling back changes temporarily so you can access your site's Navigation Settings.
- Ensure that sites/lists/pages etc. referenced by your site's navigation were not recently deleted (if so, restore from the recycle bin)
- Be sure that all resources referenced by your site's navigation are checked in / published
- Verify that Navigation Settings are unavailable to the most privileged user (farm admin)